# Need assistance with serial data between PC and Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

With help from a friend I have written a sketch for my Mega2560 that talks to a PC application via serial at 9600 baud.  The PC application send an S which instructs the mega to send variable values without any delimiters.  The PC application then creates a string from the data which is split to fill text boxes.  Some elements of these text boxes can then be changed and clicking a button makes the PC application build a string, prefixed by R# and using <> as delimiters.  It then tags an S on the end.  This string is then sent to the Mega, which as it detects the R and # reads the delimited data into a 43 element array. Once it reads the S it then runs the send function again to confirm the changes.

As a stand alone program this works -

I then added in functions for reading four Ds18B20's, four DHT11's an RTC and displaying this on a TFT.  These routines were added as separate contained voids and called in order from the main loop.  When testing the serial it nolonger works.  I either have to click on the get data button multiple times for it to read and display the info.  Sending updated information back gets lost in transit (I've used a com port sniffer and it shows data passing out to the mega).  Lastly, it's no longer accepting the updates when it does work - and having sent data back a second time it still reads the same as before the values were changed.  When the coms fails the mega seems to have locked up, so it's stuck in the comms section, presumably as one of the IF/Then conditions hasn't been met because it's run out of data.  But the routine wasn't changed from the standalone code which worked fine.

Hopefully this is as concise as you need but still has enough information to help diagnose the possible issue.  I've tried extending delays in the PC application to see if it was that which was the cause, but even setting them to 5 seconds it still errors as described

Thanks 
Malcolm

Main loop from working standalone code

```
void loop ()
 {

loopcount = 0;

// Serial.println ("in main loop ");   // to show then program is looping the main code
// delay(3000);

 // your other 5seconds of code etc

 if(Serial.available()){             // test is S or R on comms

 int tbyte = Serial.read();

 if (tbyte == 'S'){
//  Serial.println ("send data");      // S received so Send data
  transmit ();
//   sendarray ();
   }

  if (tbyte == 'R'){                 // R received  so readstream of data
//    Serial.println ("recive data");
   readstream ();
    }
  }  
 // sendarray ();
 }

 // end of main loop
```

Subroutines from the standalone code

```
// Subroutines --------------------------------------------------

 void readstream ()  {

  while (loopcount < 2000){
    if(Serial.available() > 0){



if  (serialFlag == 0) {

   inByte = Serial.read();

  if (inByte == 0X23 ){
    serialFlag = 1;
//    Serial.println ("# receieved so delimited data follows  ");
  }
}

  if  (serialFlag == 1) {
   processInput ();
    }
   }
  }
 }



// ProcessNumber-----------------

void processNumber (const long n)
 {
// Serial.println (n);

 dataIn[i]  = n;

 //Serial.println (i);
// Serial.print (dataIn[i]);

 i++;

// Serial.println (i);


 if ( i >= 43) {
//  Serial.println (" end of data....... return to main loop");
  serialFlag = 0;     // set flag back to zero
  i = 0;

 loopcount = 2222;   // stops the Serial While Loop, though better replaced by a timer
 }
 sendarray ();
 }  


 // End of ProcessNumber-----------




 // ProcessInput--------------------

void processInput ()
 {
 static long receivedNumber = 0;
 static boolean negative = false;

 byte c = Serial.read ();

 switch (c)
   {

   case endOfNumberDelimiter:  
     if (negative)
       processNumber (- receivedNumber);
     else
       processNumber (receivedNumber);

   // fall through to start a new number
   case startOfNumberDelimiter:
     receivedNumber = 0;
     negative = false;
     break;

   case '0' ... '9':
     receivedNumber *= 10;
     receivedNumber += c - '0';
     break;

   case '-':
     negative = true;
     break;

   } // end of switch  
 } 

 // End of ProcessInput------------------
```

And the input to array

```
void sendarray ()
{
daytemp1 = (dataIn[0]);
daytemp1=daytemp1/10;
daytemp2 = (dataIn[1]);
daytemp2=daytemp2/10;
daytemp3 = (dataIn[2]);
daytemp3=daytemp3/10;
daytemp4 = (dataIn[3]);
daytemp4=daytemp4/10;

<snip>
```

Comment: reduce the code to minimum required to demonstrate the error that you are getting .... remove all the useless fluff in the code and reduce it to receiving and recognizing the Q and S ... once recognized, have the code indicate which of the two was recognized .... do not do anything else until that part works

Comment: When you contacted me elsewhere you gave the impression your problem was simply how to convert incoming serial data into a variable rather than printing it. Please confine your question to this. In particular you need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *But if I copy and paste the code into my code it keeps failing. Most often it fails to compile with error messages that might as well be in Klingon* - maybe, but **we** can understand error messages. Please post them.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2523/).

Comment: @MalcC - Is it possible to expand on what the timing issue was with the PC a bit more, if you think its something others might benefit from in the future.  (I think you should post an answer to this if you can)

Comment: @CodeGorilla not a problem.  My friend informed me that the code on the mega was taking around 4-5 seconds to complete the loop, so I added a 500ms delay between sending the R and the # in the PC application, and then added a 5 second delay after the string had been sent to the mega before the PC application sent the request to the Mega to receive data to confirm the values had been updated.  This prevents the PC application reading the buffer mid loop when the mega hadn't sent data to the com port

Comment: Prior I had used a PIC18F4620 running at 40 Mhz and didn't need such delays - maybe PICs handle communications differently, because on both projects the com port speed is set to 9600 baud, so data transmission is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, I know you are new, but this is not a very easy to understand question, please keep reading though, I am trying to help.  Your description of what you want your code to do is like trying to eat a dinner plate.  Remember no one reading this has the knowledge of the problem that you do and a diagram or three speak a million words.

If it is failing to compile you need to post the source code and the compilation error.  Without that information there is no point posting the question.  The information on what is wrong is there, unfortunately you haven't used Google's Klingon to English translator.  Seriously paste the compile errors into Google and you will get a stack of results, some of which will tell you what you have done wrong.

Your friend's code is not great.  If that really is the code (rather than a space enforced edit), then I suspect it won't compile either, because its not valid C++.  Also there are logic errors in it, you can make a number negative, but once you have you can't go positive.

**So, what can you do about it?**

Rule 1: You have to learn how to walk before running around the globe.  Part of your requirement is to read Q or S from the serial line.  So write a program of YOU OWN that does just that (I mean don't copy one of a web site/friend).

- Write a program that reads the serial line.
- When you press Q it prints "You pressed Q!"
- When you press S it prints "You pressed S!"
- When you press any other key it prints "You pressed something else"
- What happens when you press s or q?

Then build up step by step, keep back ups of everything, because you will break it at some point.

Other rules, which will contradict rule 1, will be available once you have mastered number one :)

Good luck and if you get stuck again, please post here again

```
 (small example code + error messages + output + expectations) = good post
```

Comment: How do I reply to a reply... other than hit the answer button, I have an update, but still have an issue - sorry for posting loads of info in previous post - Can't win as most forums ask for the full code and detailed explanation rather than just the bit where an error occurs

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify it. We don't want snippets of code, however your private email to me said *I'm looking for a means of taking the numbers between the two delimiters and placing them into variables.*. That sounds simple enough. Your posted question far exceeds that problem.

Comment: OK - I'll edit the original post

Comment: Problem resolved  by increasing delay in the PC application - please close / delete this post

Comment: @MalcC - I would keep open, because it makes a good point that  the Arduino isn't quite as quick as a PC and sometimes you can encounter issues because you forget that the Arduinos are running at <1% of the PCs speed.  (Well I never considered speed might be an issue anyway)

Comment: @CodeGorilla - that's a fair point.  If Nick or the other admin team feel the same then by all means leave it open.  As explained above when using a PIC at 40Mhz, the main loop is probably shorter and processing subroutines are quicker, which might have thrown me whilst porting it to the mega.  Anyway, I hope that it helps others who are writing PC applications to send and receive data from an arduino device.